# Get Parseable Timezone

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs

I am using [Momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) and [Momentjs Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) to handle dates / timezones.

I'm attempting to have a date that is input from a user in a specific time zone and convert it to the local time in their own time zone.  It doesn't look like Moment's Timezone library supports the `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` format for setting the time zone.

```
function calculateLocalTime(e) {
  var currentTz = new Date().getTimezoneOffset(),
      fromDate = moment.tz(this.value, 'GMT'),
      toDate = fromDate.tz(currentTz);

  $('to-time').val(toDate.format(dateFormat));
}
```

I've also attempted to extract the three-letter time zone from the normal `Date` object as well, but that doesn't seem to be supported either.

```
function calculateLocalTime(e) {
  var currentTz = new Date().toString().split(' ').pop().replace(/\(/gi, '').replace(/\)/gi, ''),
      fromDate = moment.tz(this.value, 'GMT'),
      toDate = fromDate.tz(currentTz);

  $('to-time').val(toDate.format(dateFormat));
}
```

Any idea on how I should be doing this using Moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment-timezone is for working with standard identifiers from the [IANA TZ Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database), such as `America/Los_Angeles`.

Moment.js supports fixed-offset zones, *independent of moment-timezone*, using the [`zone`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/timezone-offset/) function.

```
var m = moment();

// All of the following are equivalent
m.zone(480);        // minutes east of UTC, just like Date.getTimezoneOffset()
m.zone(8);          // hours east of UTC
m.zone("-08:00");   // hh:mm west of UTC  (ISO 8601)
```

However, since you said you wanted to convert to the user's *local* time zone, there's no need to manipulate it explicitly.  Just use the [`local`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/) function.

Here is a complete example, converting from an explicit IANA time zone to the user's local time zone:

```
// Start at noon, Christmas Day, on Christmas Island (in the Indian Ocean)
var m = moment.tz('2014-12-25 12:00:00', 'Indian/Christmas');

// Convert to whatever the user's local time zone may be
m.local();

// Format it as a localized string for display
var s = m.format('llll');
```

For me, running this in the US Pacific time zone, I get `"Wed, Dec 24, 2014 9:00 PM"`.  The result will vary depending on where the code is run.